# Magento2.3.1: Images not displaying

Tags: product-images, magento2.3.1

[image]

Images are not displaying in magento2.3.1.

https://www.depoto.com/test-product.html

[image]

1. I gave the permissions for media folder 777 already.
2. We are not using any extension which relates to the product

I have run all the following commands, but no use.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: As i can see, you are using porto theme, 1. make sure there is media images folder in the pub folder. 2.  run this command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 3. if still image not shows then run this command php bin/magento catalog:images:resize. make sure please flush cache after run this commands.Thanks

Comment: please check the updated question. I tried but no change. I enabled the cache in cache management

Comment: please check in admin there will be lazy loader setting in theme section just disable it , i think tab name some thing like website speed where is that setting

Comment: in porto setting panel Disable Lazyload for Product Images  is in no

Comment: it has lazy loader see i have just copy class from porto theme demo product-image-photo default_image porto-lazyload porto-lazyload-loaded

Comment: sorry i didn't understand clearly

Comment: @AnsarHusain same issue for me in magento 2.3.1 category page and product page image not showing

Comment: Hello @RakeshDonga are you using Porto theme ?

Comment: yes......... @AnsarHusain

Comment: @RakeshDonga   ok can you check in admin theme settings there is one section performance section just disable lazy load from here

Comment: but this is last way.. man!!!,  i want to solve this without change anywhere configuration

Comment: Hello, Same issue I didn't use Porto theme. any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Store -> Configuration -> Disable Lazyload for Product Images: Yes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:-

Replace “`Option FollowSymLinks`” with “`Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`” in `pub/media/.htaccess` file and `pub/.htaccess` file